# findIndex() javascript array object

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
 var array = [{"one":1, "two":2},{"one":3, "two":4}];

            var result = array.findIndex(function (value) {
                if (value === 2) {
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            });

            console.log(result);
```

i keep getting '0' in the console.
how should i change (value ===2) ?
i have tried change to (value === {"two":2})
but still return '0'.

is there any other array method that suitable ?

Comment: Because you are doing `return true` in every case. Also what does `value === 2` means. value will be an object

Comment: which property do you like to check? there is no `value`in the array.

Comment: value will never be `2` it will be either `{"one":1, "two":2}` or `{"one":3, "two":4}`

Comment: put a console.log into your findindex callback before the if()..and print the value passed to the callback. You might get some understanding as to what you the value is and what you are checking it with.

Comment: @JaromandaX i just want the index of {"one":1, "two":2} to show how should i change if (value === 2) ?

Comment: @ZacharyLordford you will have to take a property that you are looking for and then check its value. `return value[propertyToCkeck] === valueToCheck`. `.findIndex` expects a callback and would break if callback returns true and return that iteration's index

Comment: @JaromandaX *i just want the index of* and then *findIndex is the wrong method to use*. Little ambiguous. It is the correct method

Comment: @Rajesh i found my answer u can stop being sarcastic now and tq for effort https://stackoverflow.com/a/44383203/7045859

Comment: @ZacharyLordford * sarcastic*? I was being generic. I meant no offense mate. And glad you found your solution. :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to check one of the properties of the objects of the array. Then return the result of the check.

```js
var array = [{ one: 1, two: 2 }, { one: 3, two: 4 }],
    result = array.findIndex(function(object) {
        return object.two === 2;
    });

console.log(result);
```

Comment: which, ironically, will also result in `0` being output - amazed the OP thought `0` was incorrect :p

Comment: Oh, I wasn't disagreeing with your answer :p

Comment: sorry for asking @NinaScholz if the result less that zero means that it not match right ?

Comment: right it returns `-1`, because this number is not a real index of an array.

Comment: thank you so much i'm still learning.. and u help a lot.. again thank u @NinaScholz

Comment: yoi may have a look here, too: [`Array#findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)

Answer (score 0):

Its first argument of the array .change with `value.two` .its object property not a array

```js
var array = [{"one":1, "two":2},{"one":3, "two":4}];
            var result = array.findIndex(function (value) {
                               return value.two == 2;
            });
            console.log(result);
```